# Compiling a summation

Tags: performance-tuning

I have a sum over Legendre polynomials which I'm trying to speed up. I've come across the suggestion of using `Compile` to speed up code in previous answers around this topic, but I can't figure out from the documentation how to apply `Compile` to this function, or whether this is even the right approach to be trying.

The function `g` is computed outside of this function, and is nearly instantaneous. But computing `fout` once I get up to n=40 or so, even over 12 cores, is taking over a minute on my computer, and I could really do with speeding it up.

Any suggestions on speeding this up? Or advice on how to use `Compile` with this?

```
fout[nu_, s_, n_, i_, p_] := 
     Block[{U, f2}, If[i == 1, {U = U1}, {U = U2}];  

fin = g[z, s, 20, i]; 

ParallelTable[2 π p Sum[U[m] fin[[k + 1]] Integrate[z^k LegendreP[m, 1, z]  
         LegendreP[t, 1, z], {z, -1, 1}], {m, 0, n}, {k, 0, 20}], {t, 0, n}, 
         Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]]
```

Comment: Do not use UpperCase for symbols and variables. `N` especially is used by Mathematica. ?N for more information

Comment: Could we have the definition of `g`? Also, is the bottleneck `Sum` or `Integrate`?(you can do `AbsoluteTiming` separately on them to find out).

Comment: I recommend first generating tables of integrals for a few sample values of `k`.  If you do so, you will discover that the resulting matrices are symmetric and also that more than half of the elements are zero.  This observation should speed your calculation greatly.

Comment: Thanks @Nasser, I've adjusted that.

Comment: @Madhi: `g` is rather long to add in here. But what it basically does is sum over the Legendre polynomials, turn this sum into a polynomial in $z$ and finally take the coefficients of the polynomial to put into `fout`. The bottleneck also seems to be on `Integrate` rather than `Sum`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey :I had noticed this before but I'm not sure how to use this observation within the code.

Comment: `Compile` is unlikely to help here given [List of compilable functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A moderate decrease in `AbsoluteTiming` can be achieved simply by not performing `Integrate` in cases where it is known to yield `0`.  Use as the test case as slightly simplified version of the code in the Question.

```
f0[n_] := ParallelTable[Sum[ Integrate[z^k LegendreP[m, 1, z] LegendreP[t, 1, z], 
            {z, -1, 1}], {m, 0, n}, {k, 0, 20}], {t, 0, n}, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]
```

Then, `f0[20] // AbsoluteTiming` takes about `45 sec` on my 4-processor laptop.  This can be reduced to `14 sec` with

```
f[n_] := ParallelTable[Sum[If[EvenQ[t + m + k], Integrate[z^k LegendreP[m, 1, z] 
           LegendreP[t, 1, z], {z, -1, 1}], 0], {k, 0, 20}, 
           {m, Max[t - k, 0], Min[t + k, n]}], {t, 0, n}]
```

The corresponding times for `n == 40` are `411 sec` and `99 sec`.

It seems likely that additional savings can be achieved, but the approach here is straightforward and easy to implement.